# TypeScript - Errors in a Utility Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface

I have the following utility method. Which takes two parameters, `inputValue` and `selectOptions`.

```
export interface SelectType {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

const checkCaseSensitiveSelectUtil = (inputValue: SelectType, selectOptions: SelectType[]): any => {
  const exactValueExists = selectOptions.find(input => input.value === inputValue);
  const valueIsNotEmpty = inputValue.trim().length;

  return !exactValueExists && valueIsNotEmpty;
};

export default checkCaseSensitiveSelectUtil;
```

But I get the following errors:
1. On `input.value === inputValue` I get the following:

```
(parameter) input: SelectType
This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'SelectType' have no overlap.ts(2367)
```

2. On `trim` I get this one:

```
Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'SelectType'.ts(2339)
```

Anyone knows how to actually make those two errors go away. I mean, since the paramters are of that exact type, is my only option to convert them both to any?

Comment: your parameter inputValue is not strin but object ! inputValue: SelectType... you probably need to compare property of this object... nput.value === inputValue.label (or inputValue.value)

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand what you are saying. Could you provide a bit more info at the problem? Maybe an example? Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**

You're comparing `input.value` (of type string) with `inputValue` (of type `SelectType`). A possible solution would be to compare the value of `input` with the value of `inputValue`.

```js
selectOptions.find(input => input.value === inputValue.value);
```

**2.**

```js
const valueIsNotEmpty = inputValue.trim().length;
```

As `inputValue` is not the value but an instance of `SelectType` you can't just trim it.

Try to get the value (a string)

```js
const valueIsNotEmpty = inputValue.value.trim().length;
```

You should consider renaming your variables. The naming is kind of confusing ;)